# React Native import RNFS get Native module cannot be null

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I'm developing a react-native application, when I try `import RNFS from "react-native-fs"` I get the following message:

```
Invariant Violation: Native Module Cannot Be Null
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: did u link properly ?

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz i use ```react-native link react-native-fs``` but issue remain. I also drag the file `node_modules/react-native-fs/RNFS.xcodeproj` into XCode editor ( inside Libraries folder ) but issue remain

Comment: I also insert `pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'` into Podfile

Comment: you did pod install ? and the project compile in xcode ?

Comment: Yes I did `pod install` and the xcode project compiles! But if I `import RNFS from "react-native-fs"` I get the error message and if I comment that the error disappear

Comment: version  of   RN? For RN >= 0.61 please install react-native-fs at version >= @2.16.0!

Comment: `"react": "16.13.1", "react-native": "0.62.2", "react-native-fs": "2.16.6"`

Comment: try restart all caches, delete all your changes and try again. really weird